# Trying to retrieve user entered values in controller and adding it to mysql database in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value="addPerson", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addPerson(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String Fname, @RequestParam(value="pwd", required=false) String Lname){
        Person person= new Person(Fname,Lname);
        crudService.addPerson(person);
        return "Successfully added " + Fname;
}    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="yellow">
    <form action="addPerson" method="get"></form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Your Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Password</td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="pwd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I have placed my html file inside `src/main/resources/static/NewFile.html` and it's not working if I use controller like `(@RequestMapping("/"))` it was just returning string instead of the view.Besides that I'm giving `http://localhost:80/NewFile.html` to access it and in that if I enter dynamic values and submit, it doesn't go to the specific controller.

I am new to this `Springboot`. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: if it is hitting the API then use debugger to follow the flow and get the problem

Comment: when i try to access that api using http://localhost:80/addPerson, it gives error like this There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.gmt.crud.person.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.gmt.crud.person.Person

Comment: But when i try to go through Html page ,enter values and hit submit it wont go to that api. It just stuck.

Comment: Change ->return "Successfully added " + Fname; as -> return "NewFile.html" and put your html file under webcontent folder.

Comment: I tried it,but its not working.

Comment: what yon can do it to check your api and HTML page , you can check API by google extension API, so that you will know that there is no problem with API, if there is no problem in API then something is wrong in HTML part, you can google it how to use google extension Advance rest client

Comment: I am a stupid guy. I did mistake in that html page, i didn't include that text box values inside that <form>.Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use @Controller instead of @RestController. It'll return the view instead of string.